# Transferring Microsoft Access database to Amazon's Titan

Tags: amazon-web-services, ms-access, titan, gremlin

I have created a pretty extensive access database and am trying to import it onto Amazon Web Service's Titan. To do this I am trying to export via CSV files.  My question is, is there a way to do this all at once or will I have to do it table by table and redefine the relationships in gremlin?

Answer (score 2):

Neither Titan nor Gremlin have inherent CSV Upload capabilities, so your best bets are going to be either to find / write a tool that can transform your DB data to GraphML or Graphson, or write your own tool that can upload CSV data using gremlin/titan.

I have written a decently generalized CSV Gremlin uploader, specific to IBM Graph. I would like to make it open-source, it's just not there yet. But if you choose to go this route, do tell me and I can help if you want.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate the previous answer. Titan does not have any migration capabilities at this stage, so you would have to create one yourself.

However, myself and some colleagues have recently released a database running on top of Titan called [MindmapsDB](https://mindmaps.io/). This open source platform does include a CSV and SQL migrator as well as a more structured approach to graph databases.